# yfinance - not giving data for some tickers (just plain info)?

Tags: python, yfinance

I am trying yfinance, and it's giving me error. I am using ticker AAALY
|Aareal Bank Ag on OTCBB

There are other examples as well, how do I get data for these?

Code:

```py
import yfinance as yf

yft  = yf.Ticker('AAALY')

print(yft.info)
```

I am getting results for other tickers like AMZN, AAPL etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Please see the package documentation for the available methods

  - [`yfinance`: Quick Start](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance#quick-start) shows all of the `Ticker` module methods.
- Use `.isin`, but data may not be available, so put the method call in a `try-except` block.
- To download financial data use the following line

  - `df = yf.download(['AAALY'], group_by='Ticker', period='30d')`
  - [How to deal with multi-level column names downloaded with yfinance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107801)

```py
tickers = ['AAALY', 'MSFT', 'AMZN', 'AAPL']
for t in tickers:
    data = yf.Ticker(t)
    try:
        print(data.isin)
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e)

[out]:
No tables found
US5949181045
-
US0378331005
```