# Converting a dictionary to DataFrame in python for stocks - ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Need to convert a dictionary to DataFrame in python. [My current attempt and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa6uh.jpg)

I understand I cannot use Scalar values but the dictionary is getting picked up directly from Yahoo finance API and I need all of that data to be put into a DataFrame but if I do a direct Signal_data = pd.DataFrame - it skips the Stock name which is important.

Is there any way to directly convert the entire signal_data into a DataFrame including the Stock Name which is UPL.NS and INFY.NS and the date.

Comment: The issue is solved - 

Working code that helped me  : - 
tickerStrings = ["UPL.NS","INFY.NS",]
df = yf.download(tickerStrings, group_by='Ticker', period='2d')
df = df.stack(level=0).rename_axis(['Date', 'Ticker']).reset_index(level=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the yfinance package?
If so there is detailed discussion in the following thread on how to correctly read in multiple stocks:

[How to deal with multi-level column names downloaded with yfinance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107594/how-to-deal-with-multi-level-column-names-downloaded-with-yfinance/63107801#63107801)

Answer (score 0):

The error of the code you posted is about the `index=[0]` argument you pass when you construct the `DataFrame`.

From the official pandas documentation [site](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), for creating a `DataFrame` from a Python `dict`, there is no `index` argument in the `DataFrame` construction. Try to create the `DataFrame` according to the Pandas site, and report any problems with a code sample.

Regards

Comment: I tried it without index = [0] as well.
the following code : - 
print(type(signal_data))
print(signal_data)
new = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(signal_data)

The error : 
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: signal_data = {}
ticker = ["UPL.NS","INFY.NS",]
df_list = list()
my_df_daily = pd.DataFrame()
for i in ticker:
    signal_data[i] = yf.download(i,list_date[0],list_date[1],interval = "1D")
    signal_data['ticker'] = i
    df_list.append(signal_data)
df = pd.concat(df_list)

Comment: The second comment is my current running code. I am sorry for the spacing not sure how to add it on here. But this current code gives an error @ df = pd.concat(df_list) - 
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'dict'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: I do not know why that error is there because df_list is clearly a list so I am not sure what the problem is. Again sorry for the shabby way the code is getting displayed on here

Comment: The error says that `df_list` is of type `dict`. The `df = pd.concat(df_list)` works between Series and DataFrames. You have to make the dictionary a DataFrame before concatenating.