# How to organise multiple stock data in pandas dataframe for plotting

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, plotly-python

I have over a hundred stocks *(actually crypto but that does not matter)* I wish to plot, all on the same line plot.

```py
PriceTimeList = []
# Then I populate the PriceTimeList with dictionaries, one for each stock
getData()
# I iterate through i, for example, i = "BTC-PERP", i = "APPL-PERP"
# Under 'price' key, I have priceList which is a list of closing prices 
# And I have it similarly or 'time' key
PriceTimeList.append({
    'name': i,
    'price': priceList,
    'time': timeList
})
# I create a dataframe from the list of dictionaries
PriceTimeDF = pd.DataFrame(PriceTimeList)
# I change the index to use the 'name' column of my dataframe
PriceTimeDF = PriceTimeDF.set_index('name')
```

I end up with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
┌──────────────┬──────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────┐
│              │                  │                                      │
│              │ price            │ time                                 │
├──────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────────────────────┤
│              │                  │                                      │
│ BTC-PERP     │ [1,2,3,4,5]      │ [1654052651, 1654052690, 1654052699] │
│              │                  │                                      │
│ APPL-PERP    │ [1,2,3,4,5]      │ [1654052651, 1654052690, 1654052699] │
│              │                  │                                      │
│ ETH-PERP     │ [1,2,3,4,5]      │ [1654052651, 1654052690, 1654052699] │
│              │                  │                                      │
│ TSLA-PERP    │ [1,2,3,4,5]      │ [1654052651, 1654052690, 1654052699] │
│              │                  │                                      │
└──────────────┴──────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────┘
```

I don't know how to make a line plot from this dataframe, I don't even know if it is possible. Is there a way? Or is there a better way I should structure the data?

Comment: The easiest way is to use the Yahoo Finance module. [This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63107594/how-to-deal-with-multi-level-column-names-downloaded-with-yfinance) is helpful. To graph it, the [graphing function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/visualization.html#basic-plotting-plot) of pandas is very easy to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It maybe better if you transform the data as shown in example belo.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'stock': ['A', 'B'],
    'price': [[10,20,30,40], [1,2,3,4]],
    'time': [[1,2,3,4], [1,2,3,4]]
})

df = df.set_index(['stock']).apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index()
df
```

| stock | price | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 1 |
| A | 20 | 2 |
| A | 30 | 3 |
| A | 40 | 4 |
| B | 1 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 2 |
| B | 3 | 3 |
| B | 4 | 4 |

Then, use `plotly.express` to plot the line chart of each stocks by using

```
import plotly.express as px
px.line(df, color='stock', x='time', y='price')
```

Output:

[image]