# FutureWarning: DataFrame.groupby with axis=1 is deprecated. Do `frame.T.groupby(...)` without axis instead

Tags: python, pandas, axis

I have been using these two lines to get stock data:

```
df = yf.download(tickers, group_by="ticker")
d = {idx: gp.xs(idx, level=0, axis=1) for idx, gp in df.groupby(level=0, axis=1)}
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/66989947/21955590.

While it works fine, I can't figure out how to avoid getting the warning in the title.

How should this code be rewritten with `df.T.groupby` without the `axis=1` without causing an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: In fact, you don't need `groupby`:

```
d = {ticker: df[ticker] for ticker in df.columns.levels[0]}
```

---

There is a [discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/51203) about `groupby(axis=1)` on github.

Another solution is to stack the ticker level:

```
d = {idx: gp.xs(idx, level=1) for idx, gp in df.stack(level=0).groupby(level=1)}
```

Output:

```
>>> d
{'AAPL':                   Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close       Volume
 Date                                                                               
 1980-12-12    0.128348    0.128906    0.128348    0.128348    0.099449  469033600.0
 1980-12-15    0.122210    0.122210    0.121652    0.121652    0.094261  175884800.0
 1980-12-16    0.113281    0.113281    0.112723    0.112723    0.087343  105728000.0
 1980-12-17    0.115513    0.116071    0.115513    0.115513    0.089504   86441600.0
 1980-12-18    0.118862    0.119420    0.118862    0.118862    0.092099   73449600.0
 ...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...          ...
 2023-10-02  171.220001  174.300003  170.929993  173.750000  173.750000   52164500.0
 2023-10-03  172.259995  173.630005  170.820007  172.399994  172.399994   49594600.0
 2023-10-04  171.089996  174.210007  170.970001  173.660004  173.660004   53020300.0
 2023-10-05  173.789993  175.449997  172.679993  174.910004  174.910004   48527900.0
 2023-10-06  173.800003  177.990005  173.179993  177.490005  177.490005   57224100.0
 
 [10795 rows x 6 columns],
 'MSFT':                   Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close        Volume
 Date                                                                                
 1986-03-13    0.088542    0.101563    0.088542    0.097222    0.060396  1.031789e+09
 1986-03-14    0.097222    0.102431    0.097222    0.100694    0.062553  3.081600e+08
 1986-03-17    0.100694    0.103299    0.100694    0.102431    0.063632  1.331712e+08
 1986-03-18    0.102431    0.103299    0.098958    0.099826    0.062014  6.776640e+07
 1986-03-19    0.099826    0.100694    0.097222    0.098090    0.060936  4.789440e+07
 ...                ...         ...         ...         ...         ...           ...
 2023-10-02  316.279999  321.890015  315.179993  321.799988  321.799988  2.057000e+07
 2023-10-03  320.829987  321.390015  311.209991  313.390015  313.390015  2.103350e+07
 2023-10-04  314.029999  320.040009  314.000000  318.959991  318.959991  2.072010e+07
 2023-10-05  319.089996  319.980011  314.899994  319.359985  319.359985  1.696560e+07
 2023-10-06  316.549988  329.190002  316.299988  327.260010  327.260010  2.564550e+07
 
 [9469 rows x 6 columns]}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do `df.T.groupby(...)` then transpose back:

```py
import yfinance as yf

tickers = ["AAPL", "F"]

df = yf.download(tickers, group_by="ticker")
d = {idx: gp.T.xs(idx, level=0, axis=1) for idx, gp in df.T.groupby(level=0)}

print(d)
```

Prints:

```
[                       0%%                      ]
[*********************100%%**********************]  2 of 2 completed
{'AAPL':                   Open        High         Low       Close   Adj Close        Volume
Date                                                                                
1972-06-01         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN           NaN
1972-06-02         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN         NaN           NaN

...
```

Comment: Thank you, Corralien and Andrej Kesely. Both solutions are great--tried so select both with the check mark.

Comment: This code works: `d = {idx: gp.xs(idx, level=1) for idx, gp in df.stack(level=0).groupby(level=1)}` but the other two suggestions have stopped working.